# Declare and use variable in YAML (Percy.io)

Tags: ansible, yaml, percy

Hi I have a YAML file that looks like this -

```
- name: Name 1
  url: http://localhost:8080/page1
- name: Name 2
  url: http://localhost:8080/page2
- name: Name 3
  url: http://localhost:8080/page3
```

As you can see that `http://localhost:8080/` is a common section of the `url` property.
Is there a way to declare a variable like `hostname` and reuse it across the file?

I went through [this](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/YAMLSyntax.html) doc and tried the following but it doesnt work -

```
- hostname: "{{http://localhost:8080}}"
- name: Name 1
  url: {{hostname}}/page1
- name: Name 2
  url: {{hostname}}/page2
- name: Name 3
  url: {{hostname}}/page3
```

But this doesnt work. Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to toss this suggestion in, you it looks like you're doing this for the base URL of the site you're snapshotting. You can pass a `--base-url` flag to the `snapshot` command:

```sh
$ npx percy snapshot --base-url http://localhost:8080 snapshots.yml
```

`snapshots.yml` could be:

```yaml
- name: Name 1
  url: /page1
- name: Name 2
  url: /page2
- name: Name 3
  url: /page3

## or

- url: /page1
- url: /page2
- url: /page3
```

[Relevant Percy CLI PR](https://github.com/percy/cli/pull/382)

Answer (score 1):

For example, the playbook

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    hostname: "http://localhost:8080"
    l1:
      - name: Name 1
        url: "{{ hostname }}/page1"
      - name: Name 2
        url: "{{ hostname }}/page2"
      - name: Name 3
        url: "{{ hostname }}/page3"
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: l1
```

gives

```yaml
ok: [localhost] => 
  l1:
  - name: Name 1
    url: http://localhost:8080/page1
  - name: Name 2
    url: http://localhost:8080/page2
  - name: Name 3
    url: http://localhost:8080/page3
```

---

When you put the items of the list into a file, e.g.

```yaml
shell> cat name-url.yml
- name: Name 1
  url: "{{ hostname }}/page1"
- name: Name 2
  url: "{{ hostname }}/page2"
- name: Name 3
  url: "{{ hostname }}/page3"
```

use [*lookup*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup.html) plugin  *template* and convert the YAML string to a list, e.g. the playbook below gives the same result

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    hostname: "http://localhost:8080"
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        l1: "{{ lookup('template', 'name-url.yml')|from_yaml }}"
    - debug:
        var: l1
```